# Собственный класс исключений в python. Если условие не повторяется, повторить ввод данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
zapas = {'fuel': 400, 'height': 0, 'v0': 0, 'uskor': 0} # Обновляемые данные
fuel_pod = 0 # сюда записывает значение пользователь

def ostatki():
    return zapas['fuel'] - fuel_pod # определяем сколько осталось топлива

class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__('не знаю что тут писать'):
        ostatki() < 0 # Если топлива меньше нуля, то это ошибка

while zapas['fuel'] > 0:
    global fuel_pod
    try:
        fuel_pod = float(input('Введите количество топлива: '))
    except (Exception):
        print('Столько топлива нет')
```

Пользователь вводит количество используемого топлива (fuel_pod). Если fuel_pod больше количества, которое есть в баках (zapas['fuel']), то этот корабль никуда не полетит. И нужно попросить пользователя еще раз ввести данные.

Как это сделать? Я пытаюсь через добавление собственного класса исключения, но не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К примеру так.

Минимально работающий пример:

```py
zapas = {"fuel": 400, "height": 0, "v0": 0, "uskor": 0}  # Обновляемые данные


def ostatki(fuel_pod):
    return zapas["fuel"] - fuel_pod  # определяем сколько осталось топлива


class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message="Нет столько топлива"):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)


while zapas["fuel"] > 0:
    try:
        fuel_pod = float(input("Введите количество топлива: "))
        if ostatki(fuel_pod) < 0:
            raise MyError
    except (MyError) as e:
        print(e)
```

Все исключения наследуются от базового класса исключения.
Вот ссылка на документацию https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#syntax-errors

Ну а дальше удачи вам в кодинге.

**UPD Данные в словаре не обновляются, предлагаю это решить вам**

Comment: Спасибо, я увидел в интернете код: class MyError(Exception)..... и нифига не понял, что я должен подставлять, а оказывается это и было уже решение :)

То есть по факту, я могу дописывать

Comment: Но теперь сломался стандартный expept. Т.е я пишу не численные символы, а он ругается в консоле, и не выдает сообщение об ошибке

Comment: Да, всё верно, у вас не стандартный except сломался, вы на входе конвертируете число во float python, если python не может преобразовать ввод во float он выбросит в данном случае ошибку ValueError: could not convert string to float . Решение, перехватывайте и проверяйте ввод. Рекомендую вам ознакомиться с преобразованием типов в питоне.